# Pluralization issues within spring boot project

Tags: java, spring, internationalization, pluralize, icu4j

Currently I'm using Spring-boot + Thymeleaf and multiple languages. I can't find any easy way to use ICU4j with these. Essentially, as I get it, all what is need is to replace `ResourceBundleMessageSource` and its `MessageFormat`  with the ICU4J variant. But I can't make it work together.

Maybe there is some examples of such projects or any other examples of pluralization functionality in Spring (such as [this](https://github.com/avityuk/ginger)).

Comment: What have you tried so far.

Comment: @M.Deinum I tried custom ResourceBundleMessageSource  with https://github.com/meticoeus/spring-icu, + some settings for Thymeleaf, but apparently I'm missing something

Comment: Instead of adding vague description. Add some code configuration that you tried and expected to work but didn't. Explain what didn't work.

Comment: @M.Deinum added the answer and the config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the typical Spring Boot 2 + Thymeleaf project it can be achieved with [this project](https://github.com/mpecan/spring-icu) and the following config:

```
@Configuration
public class YourConfigFile ...

@Bean
public ICUMessageSource messageSource() {
    ICUReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ICUReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("classpath:messages/messages");
    messageSource.setCacheSeconds(3600);
    messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    return messageSource;
}
```

You also need to add the ICU4J dependency from the maven.

In your messages.properties (messages_ru.properties in my case):

```
plural={0} {0, plural, one{пользователь}few{пользователя}other{пользователей}}
```

Using:

```
<span th:text="#{plural(0)}"></span>
<span th:text="#{plural(1)}"></span>
<span th:text="#{plural(2)}"></span>
<span th:text="#{plural(10)}"></span>
```

If you have troubles with finding messages.properties end getting errors like `??plural_ru??`, check your location and names for these files 
`messageSource.setBasename("classpath:messages/messages")`.